# Is it possible to summarize unordered daily observations of counts in multiple time series?

Tags: time-series, modeling, descriptive-statistics, fuzzy

I have a database of items, each of which is associated with one or more daily *unordered* time series; one time series for each source it's available from on a given day.  Each observation in the source's time series for an item for a given day records the count of the item at some point during the day.

I'd like to quantify the daily "availability" of an item, considering the count from its various sources.  If the observations contained a timestamp I could simply take the last observation from the day and sum those values accross the sources.  Computing summary statistics such as the mean, variation, sum, or mode for each day/item doesn't make sense since the observations in each time series are ordinal.

Are there any known methods I can apply to the raw observations or their differences that can help quantify/summarize the availability of an item for a particular day accross sources?